# HTTP Error 502: Parent proxy unreachable

Tags: python-3.x, https, proxy, httprequest, urllib

I have done proxy settings using CNTLM and also have a script(google.py) to check proxy setting are working or not

```
import urllib.request
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://localhost:3128"})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
print(html)
```

when i run the script I'm getting following errors

```
C:\Users\asj5cob\Desktop>py -3.4 google.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google.py", line 5, in <module>
    html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 470, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 580, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 508, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 588, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
 urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Parent proxy unreacheable
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you start CNTLM by executing in your administrator cmd window?

```
net start cntlm
```